# `probemod::pickapoint` fails when reversing moderator and IV for a linear model with interaction

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I am trying to model values for an interaction, but when I input the IV and moderator one way it fails. When I reverse them it works fine. Both the IV and moderator are numeric, so its not a data type issue. Anyone know why this is happening?

Error message:

```
Error in cov[interactionterms[j], interactionterms[j]] :  subscript out of bounds
```

Example

```
library(probemod)
lm.model<-lm(mpg~cyl*disp,data=mtcars)
## FAILS
ppick<-pickapoint(lm.model, dv="mpg", iv="disp", mod="cyl", method='meansd')
## WORKS FINE
ppick<-pickapoint(lm.model, dv="mpg", iv="cyl", mod="disp", method='meansd')
```

Comment: What does `traceback()` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your regression model is specified as `cyl*disp`, so the interaction term is `cyl:disp`. **Order counts**.

If you specify `iv = "disp"` and `mod = "cyl"`, `pickapoint` will look for `disp:cyl` *(trace the local variable `interactionterms` and you will see it)* but there is no such term in `lm.model`.

Covariance matrix has dimnames:

```
#            (Intercept)          cyl         disp      cyl:disp
#(Intercept) 25.04638446 -3.770034504 -0.162461470  2.219922e-02
#cyl         -3.77003450  0.705917580  0.017132037 -2.807237e-03
#disp        -0.16246147  0.017132037  0.001600197 -1.929310e-04
#cyl:disp     0.02219922 -0.002807237 -0.000192931  2.448097e-05
```

therefore you get "subscript out of bounds" error when looking for `disp:cyl`.